# How can I reparent a WPF UIElement?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, uielement

How can I reparent an `UIElement` to another Window? I have set Content to null prior to closing the Window. Afterwards a new Window is started and the `UIElement` is set to the Content of that Window.

This gives an InvalidOperationException: "Het opgegeven element is al het logische onderliggende element van een ander element. Koppel dit eerst los."

Unfortunately my windows is dutch. The rough translation is as follows: "The specified element is already the logical child element of another element. Disconnect it first."

The thing I don't understand is that I have decoupled it, but still it gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just making the content null will not effect the parent child relation ship. You need to use **RemoveLogicalChild** function of window to remove the `UIElement` as child of the previous window and then attach it to new window.

Comment: I get the same error when using RemoveLogicalChild. In conjunction with RemoveVisualChild I still get the same error..

Comment: Can you provide with a code sample as RemoveLogicalChild fuction works great for me.